# How do I protect my mining rig from brownouts and electrical surges?

Tags: mining-setup, energy-consumption, risk-mitigation

My mining rig consumes 1,250w.  What additional information do I need, or how do I shop for a product that will protect me from Brownouts and Electrical surges.

I'm not interested in UPS functionality, however I'm mostly concerned about protecting the equipment and would rather shut the rig down than pay the expense incurred with a battery backed UPS over a long duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need whats called a Power Filter.

There are varying levels of filters, some cut the tops off of AC signals, others take dirty input current and consume it, then create a completely new AC signal for device use.

The C2 is a good intro, but if you want superior protection, look for something called a Power Conditioner.

Here are links to the current leading brand:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=shop&q=apc+power+filter

http://www.apc.com/products/category.cfm?id=15&subid=85